# In which Kalpa did Shiva fall at Lord Rama's feet?

Tags: shiva, puranas, rama, padma-purana, kalpa

[Padma Purana 5.5.46](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365357.html):

> Śiva fell at his [Lord Raam's] feet
>
> “**You are the only Puruṣa** (i.e. the Supreme Being)
>
> With a portion of you, **you create and destroy the universe.**
>
> You who are formless, are **the highest cause** of the entire world.
>
> At the time of creation (you exist) in the form of **Brahmā**, In protecting (the world) you are full of your lustre; and at the time of the final destruction of the world (you are) I known as **Śarva (i.e. Śiva)**.
>
> O you kind one, **forgive (me)**
>
> O Rāma, I who granted such a boon, **am really your servant. I am now pitied (by you).**”

Shiva Purana has a different version of events but I think that may be for a different Kalpa.

Comment: Padma puran belongs to Padma Kalpa, as per Matsya Puran. Thus, this ancedote (not story, as stories can be fictional) may belong to Padma Kalpa.

Comment: @Chamundadas Can you please provide sources and answer?

Comment: Kindly refer to Matsya Puran, Chapter 53, shloka 14,15.     https://archive.org/details/matsya-puran-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n223/mode/1up?view=theater     page 215 , it mentions Padmapuran belonging to Padma Kalpa.